# Optimizing Cypher query for Performance - Social Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query that we use to fetch real-time user feeds. Users have friends and users follow others as well. The query returns correct results but it takes a relatively long time to return the results (11395 ms).

I've created indexes on following properties of nodes
User(userId, IsActive, FeaturedUser)
Feed(AccessScope)

I also tried to find out if we can create indexes on relationships but without any luck.

[Query Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9qbx.png)

```
  MATCH (u:User { SpFeaturedUser: true })<-[:CREATED_BY]-(fe)-[:FEED_TYPE]->(:ServiceType{Id: 13})
                                WITH fe
                                ORDER BY fe.UpdatedUTCDateTime DESC
                                SKIP 0
                                LIMIT 100
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (fe)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (fe)-[:FEED_TYPE]->(st:ServiceType)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (fe)-[endrs:ENDORSED]->(p:Place)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Place)-[placeImage:RELATED_IMAGE]->(pImg:Image)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH(fe)< -[likes: LIKES] - ()
                                OPTIONAL MATCH(fe)< -[cmts: COMMENT_ON_FEED] - (c)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Mentions)-[:MENTIONED_IN]->(fe)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (fe)-[:RELATED_IMAGE]->(img:Image)
                                OPTIONAL MATCH (fe)-[:RELATED_SERVICE_URL]->(su)
                                WITH {
                                    Description: fe.Description,
                                    DescriptionEncoded: fe.DescriptionEncoded,
                                    EndorsementType: fe.PostType,
                                    CreatedUTCDateTime: fe.CreatedDateTime,
                                    UpdatedUTCDateTime: fe.UpdatedDateTime,
                                    StartDate: fe.StartDate,
                                    EndDate: fe.EndDate,
                                    AccessScope: fe.AccessScope,
                                    Rating: fe.Rating,
                                    EndorsementId: fe.ServiceId,
                                    ServiceTypeId: st.Id,
                                    LikeCount: Count(distinct(likes)),
                                    IsLiked: EXISTS((fe) < -[:LIKES] - (: User{ UserId: "4F97D90E-922C-4C44-8F68-8311C60D76D9"}) ),
                                    CommentsCount: Count(distinct(cmts)),
                                    LastActivity: { 
                                        en: fe.Activity, 
                                        da: fe.DanishActivity
                                        },
                                    User: {
                                        UserId: u.UserId,
                                        FirstName: u.FirstName,
                                        FileName: u.FileName,
                                        SocialMediaAttribution: {

                                        }
                                    },
                                    Endorsement_Mentions: CASE WHEN m IS NOT NULL THEN Collect(distinct {
                                        Name: m.Name,
                                        Type: m.TagType,
                                        PlaceHolder: m.Placeholder,
                                        TagID: m.TagId
                                    }) ELSE [] END ,
                                    Endorsement_Image: CASE WHEN img IS NOT NULL THEN Collect(distinct {
                                        ImageUrl: img.ImageUrl,
                                        Width: img.Width,
                                        Height: img.Height,
                                        Extension: img.Extension,
                                        CreatedUTCDateTime: img.CreatedUTCDateTime
                                    }) ELSE [] END,
                                    URLPreviews: CASE WHEN su IS NOT NULL THEN Collect(distinct {
                                      Title           : su.UrlTitle         ,
                                      Description     : su.UrlDescription   ,
                                      ImageURL        : su.PreviewImage      ,
                                      URL             : su.Url           ,
                                      Width           : su.Width         ,
                                      Height          : su.Height        ,
                                      Extension       : su.Extension     ,
                                      IsVideoUrl      : su.IsVideoUrl    ,
                                      VideoStreamUrl  : su.VideoStreamUrl,
                                      VideoType       : su.VideoType       
                                    }) ELSE [] END,
                                    Object: {
                                        ObjectId: p.ObjectId,
                                        Name: p.ObjectName,
                                        IsFollowed: EXISTS((fe)-[:ENDORSED]->()<-[:FOLLOW]-({UserId : "4F97D90E-922C-4C44-8F68-8311C60D76D9"})),
                                        AverageRating: {
                                            Count: p.ObjectAvgRating
                                        },
                                        EndorsementCount: Count(distinct(endrs)),
                                        Object_Image: CASE WHEN pImg IS NOT NULL THEN
                                              Collect(distinct {
                                                ImageUrl: pImg.ImageUrl,
                                                Width: pImg.Width,
                                                Height: pImg.Height,
                                                Extension: pImg.Extension,
                                                CreatedUTCDateTime: pImg.CreatedUTCDateTime
                                              }) ELSE [] END,
                                        Category: {
                                            CategoryId: p.CategoryId 
                                        },
                                        Country: {
                                            ShowBarometer: false
                                        }
                                    }
                                } as Feed 
            RETURN DISTINCT(Feed)
            ORDER BY Feed.UpdatedUTCDateTime DESC
```

The expected result is that this query should run fast enough to return the results within 2-3 secs as other queries are already running.

Comment: Is there a good reason for having those `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses? You do not seem to be using anything they might find. Also why do you generate empty `SocialMediaAttribution` maps?

Answer (score 0):

Since your query does not need any of the results from the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses, deleting them should speed up the query and avoid potential duplicate results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I missed the latter part of the query as I was testing it with different configuration and options. Now I've edited it and added the full query here. Can you please have a look at it?